# jquery-ui-sortable, how to prevent cancel when list gets hidden?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have several sortable lists in my page, and it's working fine to sort items between them.

Now I would like to achieve the following:

I want to start with all but one of the lists hidden. User drags an item from the visible list, moves it over a hot spot in the page where an `onMouseOver` event hides the visible list and shows the one that the user is hovering so the user can continue to drag the item into that list.

At the moment, as soon as the source list is hidden the drag gets cancelled. Can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. If you are hiding the lists by setting the css property `display` to `none`, you will not be able to detect the sortable events because that list is not rendered.

Try using `opacity` instead.

Create a class that "hides" the lists using `opacity`. I named my class `fake-hidden`. Attach that class to the sortable lists that you want to have hidden when entering your site. Use the sortable options `helper: 'clone'` and `appendTo: 'body'` so that a clone of our currently dragged item is created, this will allow us to see the item when it's parent is technically "hidden". On sortable `start` we will add some data to the currently dragged item, setting the `og-parent` to the item's first parent. On sortable `over` we will check if the new parent is not equal to the og-parent (because over fires on mousemove). If that is true we will hide the og-parent using our `fake-hidden` class and remove the class from this hovered list. Then we will set og-parent to this new sortable list.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/hsuoxjm2/).

Here is an inline example:

```js
$('.sortable-list').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sortable-list',
  items: '.item',
  helper: 'clone',
  appendTo: 'body',
  start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.data('og-parent', $(this));
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.item.data('og-parent').is($(this))) {
      ui.item.data('og-parent').addClass('fake-hidden');
      $(this).removeClass('fake-hidden');
    }
    ui.item.data('og-parent', $(this));
  }
});
```

```css
.sortable-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fake-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  background: #AF1843;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="sortable-list list-1">
      <li class="item">list 1.1</li>
      <li class="item">list 1.2</li>
      <li class="item">list 1.3</li>
      <li class="item">list 1.4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="sortable-list list-2 fake-hidden">
      <li class="item">list 2.1</li>
      <li class="item">list 2.2</li>
      <li class="item">list 2.3</li>
      <li class="item">list 2.4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="sortable-list list-3 fake-hidden">
      <li class="item">list 3.1</li>
      <li class="item">list 3.2</li>
      <li class="item">list 3.3</li>
      <li class="item">list 3.4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="sortable-list list-4 fake-hidden">
      <li class="item">list 4.1</li>
      <li class="item">list 4.2</li>
      <li class="item">list 4.3</li>
      <li class="item">list 4.4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```